# how to remove error the service is invalid please check your setup and try

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have been working away and things are going well, except suddenly 
when I try to build my project, I get the following errors in xCode:

1 - in an alert box on upon building: 
The service is invalid 
Please check your setup and try again. 
(0xE8000022).

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2160299/error-the-service-is-invalid

Answer (score 7):

just restart your ipod or iphone.