# Error : The service is invalid

Tags: iphone, objective-c, installation

I am having some problem in installing my app on the iphone as I am constantly getting the following error message

> The service is invalid
>
> Please check your setup and try again
>
> (0XE8000022)

It was running perfectly well till yesterday but since yesterday I am having this problem.

Comment: I have solved the problem... Only needed to restart the iphone

Comment: Restarting the iPhone worked for me too.
"Clean All Targets" and restarting Xcode didn't work.

Comment: Don't assume its the device your working with.  Unplug all devices, then plug in one by one to determine which one it is (restart Xcode each time) or restart all connected devices.  I had an iPad and iPhone plugged in, was using the iPhone, but it was my iPad I had plugged in to charge.

Comment: @KarSho I have already solved this problem way back in 2010 when I faced this issue. You can check my answer for the same

Answer (score 99, accepted):

I have solved the problem... Only needed to restart the iphone...

Restarting the Xcode wont work in this case. So just restart your iPhone and everything will be fine.

**EDIT:**

If you have an iPhone 5 running iOS 6.0 and have installed the "iOS Updater" app, you will also have this message.

Finishing the update process to iOS 6.0.1 will resolve the problem.

Comment: I believe Arenim answered this question several days before you. You should mark his answer as the official and not add another answer saying that his suggestion worked. Marking an answer is enough to tell people what solved your problem.

Comment: Agree with the above comment. Please select the answer given as the correct one.

Comment: Restarting won't fix it. @Brock Woolf gave perfect answer. All those steps are necessary.

Comment: It's strange but it's working. Any specific reason?

Answer (score 147):

Xcode and the GDB connection is quite temperamental. The device and your Mac can become unsynchronised with each other. My checklist for this sort of thing:

1. Restart Xcode.
2. Delete the .app from your iOS device, do a Clean then Rebuild.
3. Disconnect, reconnect device.
4. Restart iOS device (90% of the time it fixes things)
5. If all else fails, restart your Mac (unlikely but it did fix an issue once for me).

Comment: 2a: Delete DerivedData

Comment: None of these steps worked for me until I deleted the DerivedData as @AminNegm-Awad suggests. Follow https://stackoverflow.com/a/40278559/2686419 to see how.

Comment: I thought only restarting phone was required. But I had to clear the DerivedData as @AminNegm-Awad mentioned. I restarted IDE too, now it's all fine. Superb answer and comments!

Comment: 4. Restart iOS device (90% of the time it fixes things) works for me.

Comment: if there is an update available, you can do it also. Not sure that it was the cause in my case but I had to do it also..

Answer (score 11):

If you have an iPhone 5 running iOS 6.0 and have installed the "iOS Updater" app, you will also have this message.

Finishing the update process to iOS 6.0.1 will resolve the problem.

Comment: Although this problem can occur for other reasons, being halfway through the iOS Updater app install is definitely one of them.

Answer (score 4):

This error also happens if the iPhone provisioning profile has expired.

Answer (score 4):

It can be a couple of things, **the first and inmediate thing I'd check is to see if your IPhone is currently Downloading or "Preparing Update..."** whilst this is running you generally get the **"Device is invalid (0xe8000084)" / Error MT1006.**

This i found to be the most common thing. so try this first.

And if that fails: Restart your IPhone, and then if that fails restart your Mac/Xcode
and do a clean then Rebuild and deploy..

Hope this helps

Comment: You got it! Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This error happens when you try to debug an application in your IPod/IPhone and the device is code-locked or executing another application.

Make sure you can see the menu with all the app icons on the device and try to run again.

Regards

Comment: Same here. when I got this error my phone said "SIM Locked". I removed the sim and it works fine.

Answer (score 3):

If nothing works then check if your device os is compatible with your Xcode version.

Answer (score 3):

I confirm that restarting your device solves the issue.
But if your device is jailbroken with a Semi-tethered jailbreak you will loose it after a reboot.

To prevent this, do a ldrestart(soft reboot).

In order to perform it, download a terminal application from Cydia, then type:

```
su
```

Input your password when asked, the default password is "alpine".

Then type

```
ldrestart
```

Answer (score 2):

Unplugged the device and connected again with Mac solved my issue. Did not need to clean, build or restart XCode. XCode 10.2.1, iOS 12.3.1 version.

Answer (score 1):

First remove the app from iPhone before building the app from xcode.
Then **Clean All Targets** from xcode and then try to build your app again.

Comment: I tried what you told but it didn't work.I have solved it. Just needed to restart the iphone.

Comment: Kinda worked, the message still appears, but the app installs, I'm going to try and restart the device.

Answer (score 1):

SnowLeopard w/ XCode 4.2's Instruments will give this message on newer iOSes.

Answer (score 1):

I had luck by disconnecting my iPhone from my mac, and then Analyzing (Shift + Command + B or Product -> Analyze).

After that I plugged my iPhone back in and did a clean (Command + k) and then run. Worked!

Answer (score 1):

Simply restarting the device (as the alert suggests) fixed the problem, at least on iOS 12.