# Xcode Organizer - The service is invalid

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm using XCode 4.3 (on Lion) and my iPod touch 2nd generation does show up, but displays "The service is invalid" (0xE8000022). I've tried every possible combination of restarting/reconnecting the device and have even restored the OS on the device... any ideas on how to further figure this out?

Comment: Ryan...did you ever get an answer on this? I'm having the same issue on an iPad that was working fine to test and then xCode crashed and this is all I get now.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error : The service is invalid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2160299/error-the-service-is-invalid)

Answer (score 0):

EDIT - initially I suggested restarting the device but I realized you had already done this.

I think this answer might be valid:

[Error : The service is invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2160299/error-the-service-is-invalid/13268599#13268599)