# Xamarin Forms: Failed to launch the ios application on the device

Tags: iphone, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

Getting the following message when installing xamarin forms ios app in physical ios device.

> NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Please try rebooting and reconnecting the device. (0xE8000022)., NSLocalizedFailureReason=Please try rebooting and reconnecting the device. (0xE8000022).}
>   warning MT1043: Failed to launch the application using the instruments service. Will try launching the app using gdb service.
>   Launching 'appname' on the device 'iPhone'
>   warning HE0030: Could not mount developer tools on 'iPhone': Could not locate device support files.
>   warning HE0031: Failed to mount developer tools on 'iPhone'.
>   warning HE0030: Could not mount developer tools on 'iPhone': Could not locate device support files.
>   warning HE0031: Failed to mount developer tools on 'iPhone'.
>   error MT1007: Failed to launch the application 'appname' on the device 'My iPhone': Failed to launch the application 'apname 'My iPhone': Invalid Service Error (error: 0xe8000022). You can still launch the application manually by tapping on it.

I am using visual studio for mac version 7.7.3(build 43), iPhone 7(12.3.1) and xcode(Version 10.1 (10B61))

I have installed Xcode on mac, not iPhone, is Xcode need to install on iPhone for debugging the app?

I already found the same issue on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2160299/error-the-service-is-invalid). Restarted iPhone, Mac and visual studio as per the solution on that thread, but that didn't help me.

Comment: Try to update visual studio for mac

Comment: @BrunoCaceiro I am using VS Community 2017 for Mac. I checked the latest stable update of VS, latest version showing was 7.7.4.1. Or should I install the latest version of VS 2019?

Comment: Yeah, I would advise to install the latest version of VS 2019.

Comment: @BrunoCaceiro Ok I will install the latest version of 2019 and update here.

Comment: @BrunoCaceiro   **Update:**

Updated the VS to 2019. But Xcode 10.2 is required for working on VS 2019 and my current version of Xcode is 10.1. For installing Xcode 10.2 it requires Mac OS X 10.14.3 or later. But my current Mac OS version is 10.13.6. For updating Mac I need permission from top. Waiting for permission.

Comment: Are you using instruments when launching the app? Close the instruments  and clean/rebuild your project, then run again.

Comment: @BrunoCaceiro Please post it as your answer, problem solved

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update to the latest Visual Studio for Mac version (2019) as well as XCode version.

Answer (score 2):

Starting with iOS and ipadOS 16, you also have to [enable the Developer Mode](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/enabling-developer-mode-on-a-device) on each device (Settings > Privacy & Security).